# Turning simple raster file into DEM?

Tags: raster, dem, qgis-2.12

I'm using QGIS LYON 2.12.1, and I want to turn a plain gray scale raster file (that I got from Google search) into a DEM.

The aim is to apply the DEM (terrain models) function to the newly created DEM.

How would I convert the .tiff or .jpeg into a DEM with elevation data?

Comment: Please be specific: "experiment" and "run ... raster functions" tell us nothing to which we can effectively respond.  Please take a tour of our [help] to learn how this site works and what kinds of questions we can answer here.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Does this make my question any clearer?

Comment: It helps very much, thank you.  But I need to ask: exactly what distinction are you making between a "DEM with elevation data" and the data in your "plain grayscale raster file"?  If the numerical values already in that file don't work for you, then in what way do they differ from what you consider to be "elevations" (which, after all, are just numbers)?

Comment: @whuber I guess I misunderstood how the data was stored in a raster dem. Thank you for explaining that to me.